# Is there an easy way to use a base class's variables?

Tags: c++, inheritance, variables

When you have a derived class, is there an simpler way to refer to a variable from a method other than:

```
BaseClass::variable
```

**EDIT**

As it so happens, I found a page that explained this issue using functions instead:
[Template-Derived-Classes Errors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19). Apparently it makes a difference when using templates classes.

Comment: could you make your question more specific, such that you illustrate the fact that it relates to template derived classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the base class member variable is protected or public than you can just refer to it by name in any member function of the derived class.  If it is private to the base class the compiler will not let the derived class access it at all.  Example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
  int a;

private:
  int b;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  void foo()
  {
    a = 5;  // works
    b = 10; // error!
  }
};
```

There is also something to be said for keeping all member variables private, and providing getters and setters as needed.

Also, beware of "hiding" data members:

```
class Base
{
public:
  int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  int a;
};
```

This will create two variables named `a`: one in `Base`, one in `Derived`, and it will likely lead to confusion and bugs.

Comment: Just to clarify, accessing a private member of a base class will result in a compiler error.  The compiler will not ignore it and look for another match.

Answer (score 1):

Related: [Using “super” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c)