# Concise (yet still expressive) C++ syntax to invoke base class methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax, base-class

I want to specifically invoke the base class method; what's the most concise way to do this? For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
  bool operator != (Base&);
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
  bool operator != (Child& child_)
  {
    if(Base::operator!=(child_))  // Is there a more concise syntax than this?
      return true;

    // ... Some other comparisons that Base does not know about ...

    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: And also is the way I'm doing it considered a "standard"? e.g. will it work on any compilers?

Comment: KISS: keep it simple... Add is_equal function to the base class and use it in the child class.

Comment: @AlexKR: thanks for the suggestion. Though, I have a real reason why I have to use these operators..=(

Comment: The `operator!=` should be a const method, and take const parameters.

Comment: @KennyTM: thanks for the info. I intentionally left those out just to get the post up quickly. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that is as concise as it gets. `Base::operator!=` is the name of the method.

And yes, what you are doing is standard.

However, in your example (unless you have removed some code), you do not need `Child::operator!=` at all. It does the same thing as `Base::operator!=` will.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks for the remark. Though, as you have guessed, I did remove some code just to simplify the question. =)

Answer (score 5):

1

```
if ( *((Base*)this) != child_ ) return true;
```

2

```
if ( *(static_cast<Base*>(this)) != child_ ) return true;
```

3

```
class Base  
{  
public:  
  bool operator != (Base&);  
  Base       & getBase()       { return *this;}
  Base const & getBase() const { return *this;}
}; 

if ( getBase() != child_ ) return true;
```

Comment: Careful!  This only works because you are calling non-virtual functions!

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is the most concise and "standard" way to do it, but some people prefer this:

```
class SomeBase
{
public:
    bool operator!=(const SomeBaseClass& other);
};

class SomeObject: public SomeBase
{
    typedef SomeBase base;  // Define alias for base class

public:
    bool operator!=(const SomeObject &other)
    {
        // Use alias
        if (base::operator!=(other))
            return true;

        // ...

        return false;
    }
};
```

The benefits of this method is that it clarifies intention, it gives you a standard abbreviation for what could be a long base-class name, and if your base class changes, you don't have to change every use of the base.

See [Using "super" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c) for additional discussion.

(Personally, I don't care for this, and I don't recommend it, but I think it is one valid answer to the question.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning this: "... and if your base class changes, you don't have to change every use of the base." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition) return true;
return false;
```

can be abbreviated to

```
return condition;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd get rid of the if/then control structure and just return the return value of the base class operator, but otherwise what you're doing is fine.

It can be a bit more concise, though: `return ((Base&)*this) != child_;`

Comment: If he's going to do that, he may as well just get rid of the function altogether, and let the base class be called. I think it's clear that the "Some other comparisons" section should be filled in with code.