# typedef,#define

Tags: c, macros, typedef

Can anybody explain the difference between

```
#define int* char
```

and

```
typedef int* char;
```

Comment: probably you meant '#define char int*'

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, e.g. [Is typedef and #define the same in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c) - probably a homework question ?

Comment: check this one too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263252/is-typedef-just-a-string-replacement-in-code-or-somethings-else

Comment: Shame that your example is severely flawed and illegal.  I'd fix that soon before the votes to close reach the target for what is probably otherwise a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different. Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c).

`#define` is replacement which is handled during preprocessing

typedef is used to define a new type which is ignored during preprocessing

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference because both are illegal.

`int*` isn't a valid identifier for a macro, and even if you put a space in, neither is `int`, because it's a keyword and reserved. Even if you switched it to your likely intended `#define char int*`, it fails for the same reason.

And you cannot redefine the type `char`, so the `typedef` is a bust.

---

The difference, had you given examples that were legal, is that `#define` is a preprocessing directive. It only does textual replacement, before the compiling stage. Contrarily `typedef` defines a new type, and that new type identifier respects "the rules" just like any other type.

Answer (score 2):

defines are handled by a preprocessor (a program run before the actual c compiler) which works like replace all in you editor.

Typedef is handled by the c compiler itself, and is an actual definition of a new type.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a preprocessor directive. Before compiling, the text `int*` will be changed to `char`. It's something you typically don't do.

Typedef is a language instruction. It defines a new type, as [Forlan07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316474/typedef-define/3316482#3316482) just said.

Your example is very bad in either form. Fortunately though, it's illegal, as [GMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316474/typedef-define/3316536#3316536) pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

> [[`typdef`]](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html) allows you to introduce synonyms for types which could have been declared some other way. The new name becomes equivalent to the type that you wanted, as this example shows.

`define` is a [c preprocessor macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), which will just replace occurences in your code.

The particular example your are showing seems a little weird to me, though. Maybe you can add some background information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

typedef assigns alternative names to existing types. e.g:
typedef unsigned long size_t

Now in code you can replace unsigned long with size_t
unsigned long temp; is the same as size_t temp;

'#define' is a preprocessor directive. It causes the compiler to go through the source code, replacing every occurrence of macro-name with replacement-string
e.g. #define PI 3.14159

The examples that you have chosen will give compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

A type alias defined using a macro rather than a typedef has the flexibility to be undefined or redefined whereas a typedef does not.  This is why you may see type aliases defined this way.  It is both a weakness and an advantage.  The number of C libraries that define their own types with common names like UINT, DWORD or BOOL for example is countless, and the cause of many problems when using multiple third-party libraries.  At least with a macro you can force them to be undefined, or check for existing definitions; if a typedef is used, you may have a symbol clash problem than makes it difficult to integrate such code.

In C++ the problem is better overcome by encapsulating the third-party code in a namespace, then the typedef would remain the better solution to type aliases.