# Provide reason for below mentioned difference in behavior of typdef & #define

Tags: c, macros, typedef

I have gone through already existing information available on

[difference between typedef and define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202220/difference-between-typedef-and-define) & 
[typedef,#define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316474/typedef-define?rq=1)

All replies are really informative.
I just came across one more example, can anyone please provide the reason for this behavior .

**For declaring unsigned int variable** this will work:

```
#define INTEGER int
unsigned INTEGER i = 10;
```

But, it won't work in case of typedef,

*e.g.*

```
typedef int INTEGER;
unsigned INTEGER i = 10;
```

it will throw error:  *‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)*

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor just makes copies and pastes. When you write:

```
#define INTEGER int
unsigned INTEGER i = 10;
```

Before the compiler itself, the preprocessor turns the code in:

```
unsigned int i = 10;
```

However, `typedef` is treated by the compiler.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.8 Type definitions
>
> A `typedef` declaration does not introduce a new type, only a
>   synonym for the type so specified. That is, in the following declarations:
>
> ```
> typedef T type_ident;
> type_ident D;
> ```
>
> `type_ident` is defined as a `typedef` name with the type specified by the declaration
>   specifiers in `T` (known as `T`), and the identifier in D has the type ‘‘derived-declarator-
>   type-list `T` ’’ where the derived-declarator-type-list is specified by the declarators of `D`.

In other words, `<INTEGER>` is a synonym of `<int>`. But `<unsigned INTEGER>` is treated as a single type, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` creates a type alias to the exact type you have in the `typedef` declaration. That type is recognized by the compiler as a true type. In your case there will be a proper type `INTEGER`, but there is no `unsigned INTEGER` type which is why it's an error.

A macro (`#define`) is replaced before the compiler even sees it, by the preprocessor. So for the compiler the first case is simply

```
unsigned int i = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `typedef` is not an 1:1 literal text substitution. Basically, in the first case, `unsigned INTEGER` is expanded to `unsigned int`, which is a valid type name (only certain combinations of type names and qualifiers are allowed in C, and `unsigned int` is one of them.)

In the second case, however, `unsigned INTEGER` is not a valid combination of type names.