# Behavior of #define in c

Tags: c

```
#define int_p int*
int_p p1,p2,p3; // only p1 is a pointer !
```

can somebody exlplain why it is so.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263252/is-typedef-just-a-string-replacement-in-code-or-somethings-else/3263326#3263326

Comment: Stop doing that. Every coding standard in the world bans it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#define` is just a textual substitution. The code above is equivalent to

```
int *p1, p2, p3;
```

so only `p1` is a pointer. You need

```
typedef int* int_p;
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than thinking of it like this:

```
int* (p1, p2, p3);
```

think of it like this:

```
int (*p1), p2, p3;
```

As in, only the symbol with the asterisk in-front of it becomes a pointer, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

The preprocessor just does text substitution on the source code before compilation; it has no awareness of types or syntax.  After preprocessing, the lines

```
#define int_p int*
int_p p1, p2, p3;
```

expand to

```
int* p1, p2, p3;
```

Which brings us to our second point; in a declaration, the `*` binds to the nearest declarator, not the type specifier; IOW, the above declaration is parsed as

```
int (*p1), p2, p3;
```

Whitespace makes no difference; `int* p1;` is parsed the same as `int *p1;` as `int     *     p1;`.

If you want to declare all three variables as pointers, you have three choices:

1. Do it all by hand:

   ```
       int *p1, *p2, *p3;
   ```

   Use your macro, but use multiple declarations

   ```
       int_p p1;
       int_p p2;
       int_p p3;
   ```

   Create a type synonym using the `typedef` facility:

   ```
       typedef int *int_p; 
       int_p p1, p2, p3;
   ```

Unlike the preprocessor macro, the typedef is not a simple text substitution; the compiler basically creates a synonym for the type `int *`, and that synonym can be used anywhere `int *` can be used.