# Rename C Structure

Tags: c

I am working on a microcontroller project in C. The main.c file includes a header defining all of the registers as structures and chars. Unfortunately they name the registers unmeaning-full names like PORTA. Is it possible to rename the structures and variable defined in the header file to something more meaningful in my main file?

So instead of PORTA I can call it OUT without modifying the header file where it was defined.

Comment: Macros? `#define OUT PORTA`

Comment: @Mystical Macros can be tricky here -typedef is the way to go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263252/is-typedef-just-a-string-replacement-in-code-or-somethings-else/3263326#3263326

Comment: @Amarghosh Although it's not clear from the question, I have a feeling that they might actually be variable names rather than types.

Comment: Which micro and which compiler? Often there is platform specific ways.

Comment: Considering that the names correspond to specific registers/memory locations, I think it's very likely they're variable names rather than types.

Comment: You are correct, They are variable names. It is the PIC18 C compiler from Microchip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoting comment to answer:

The easiest way I can think of is to just use macros:

```
#define OUT PORTA
```

And these don't need to be in the header.

**EDIT :**

If the original names are actually names of variables (rather than types), then this is the way to go since the typedef method will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typedef` to create an alias:

```
typedef PORTA OUT;
```

Comment: ... if `PORTA` is a type and not an object.