# How can call member of a base class in sub class without knowing name of base class in C++?

Tags: c++, function, call, superclass, base-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ equivalent of “super”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424216/c-equivalent-of-super)

Is it possible to call a base class member function in a sub class, without knowing name of base class? (something like use super keyword in java)

Comment: How would you not know the name of the base class?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have an equivalent of `super`. Since it supports multiple inheritance, a `super` could refer to several different classes, not just one like in Java.

Comment: Since you must name the base class to define the derived class, you must know the name (or, at least, _a_ name) for the base class.  Then, there's nothing stopping you from `typedef base_class_name super;`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Nothing except decency, good taste, common sense, etc.

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  Sometimes this is a useful technique.  Consider a base class with a very, very long name, e.g. `std::conditional<expression, B1, B2>::type`, where `B1` and `B2` are long type names, the expression may be complex, and everything might be dependent.  I can recall having done this a few times, though I usually name the typedef `base_type` or something similar, rather than `super` (since I've never used this "Java" thing).

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a standard equivalent for `super` keyword. But there is a microsoft specific one `__super` which I think achieves the same thing if you are using visual studio.

```
// deriv_super.cpp
// compile with: /c
struct B1 {
   void mf(int) {}
};

struct B2 {
   void mf(short) {}

   void mf(char) {}
};

struct D : B1, B2 {
   void mf(short) {
      __super::mf(1);   // Calls B1::mf(int)
      __super::mf('s');   // Calls B2::mf(char)
   }
};
```

Refer: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't that do the same without the `__super::`?

Comment: @steffen It does work if there is only single inheritance and a different function name for `struct D`. In current case, first call of `mf` itself cause infinite recursion as the calling function also matches the same. if the `struct D`'s function name is not `mf`, it will generate a compiler error: `reference to 'mf' is ambiguous`.