# Inheritance and STL vector

Tags: c++, inherited

let's say i got a class "Simple" with this private var : std::vector m_listePoint; which constructor is

```
Simple(EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur c,vector<Point> listeP);
```

(couleur is inherited from her mother class)

i got another class which is "Circle" ( a child class of "Simple"), with 2 vars : 1 Point, 1 radius
Here is the constructor i ve tried :

```
Cercle::Cercle( const Point centre, const double rayon, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v)
{
        m_rayon = rayon;
        vector<Point> liste;
        liste.push_back(centre);
        __super::Simple(v,liste);

}
```

I got an error saying Simple doesnt have a default constructor.

I know that basically i should do this way :

```
 Cercle::Cercle( const Point centre, const double rayon, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v) : m_rayon(rayon), Simple(...)
```

the problem is : how to build the vector then?

This might be a stupid question i don't know, i come from java, this is why i used super and might be bad way...

Comment: i ve found it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424216/c-equivalent-of-super

Comment: What is ... in your example?

Comment: you cannot call another constructor from the body of another function, even another constructor.

Comment: @Mordachai Well, you can...it just doesn't do what one might expect.

Comment: how can i do then? i want to put my point in a vector, and then send it to "Simple"

Comment: @Mordachai You can, you do it in the initializer list.

Comment: Do not use non-standard C++ extensions. `__super` is one.

Comment: @BWG Do you not know what "body" means?  Yes, from the initialize list.  No, not from the body.

Comment: why it's marked as duplicated now ? the url is nothing about my problem

Comment: @Mordachai Oh, sorry I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the vector constructor that makes a vector of `n` copies of an element:

```
Cercle::Cercle( const Point centre, const double rayon, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v) 
       : m_rayon(rayon), Simple(v, std::vector<Point>(1, centre)) { /* ... */ }
```

Or, in C++11, use the initializer list constructor:

```
Cercle::Cercle( const Point centre, const double rayon, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v) 
       : m_rayon(rayon), Simple(v, {centre}) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: how you do if you got 2 values to put in the vector ?

Comment: @Niko The initializer list method still works. Otherwise, write a helper function that constructs and returns the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Vector has a useful constructor here: `vector(size_type count, const T& value, <irrelevent>)` that makes it easy to construct a vector with a single element: `vector<Point>(1, centre)`.

Like so:

```
Cercle::Cercle( const Point centre, const double rayon, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v)
    :m_rayon(rayon),
    Simple(v, vector<Point>(1, centre))
{
}
```

If you have multiple elements, make a simpler helper function or use an `initializer_list`

initializer_list

```
Rect::Rect( const Point topleft, const Point botright, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v)
    :m_rayon(rayon),
    Simple(v, {topleft, botright})
{
}
```

helper function:

```
std::vector<Point> make_from_two(point one, point two) {
    vector<Point> liste;
    liste.push_back(one);
    liste.push_back(two);
    return liste;
} 

Rect::Rect( const Point topleft, const Point botright, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v)
    :m_rayon(rayon),
    Simple(v, make_from_two(topleft, botright))
{
}
```

Comment: how you do if you got 2 values to put in the vector ?