# Borland / Delphi alternative to __super keyword

Tags: c++, delphi, compiler-construction, c++builder

Keyword `__super` is Microsoft specific. It is used to access virtual methods of parent class. Do you know alternative keywords for Borland C++/Delphi compilers?

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    virtual void DoSomething();
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
    virtual void DoSomething();
};

void MyBaseClass::DoSomething()
{
    // some code
}

void MyDerivedClass::DoSomething()
{
    __super::DoSomething();  // calls implementation of base class - no need to know name of base class

    // implementation specific to derived class adding new functionality
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent in Delphi is [`inherited`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Inherited). So far as I know, there is no equivalent in C++ Builder and of course `__super` is a non-standard MS extension.

Comment: Still no __super in C++ 2011 standard. You have to know your parent class name. Which sucks, IMHO.  I like the idea of "non propagation of variable details".  So I guess, in C++ 2011 you'd typedef once, and avoid repetition of the parent classname throughout the unit.

Comment: @WarrenP In the face of multiple inheritance, `__super` is tricky to implement. I'm sure there are good reasons for C++ being the way it is.

Comment: Did you know? super you can put on the first line only , while inherited can be called from any line in the procedure/function? body.

Comment: This related question show an alternative to `__super` (along with a mention of the great book "The Design and Evolution of C++", which I used to own but my dog ate.): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I have that book on my desk right now. Your dog has good taste!!

Answer (score 8):

- Delphi: `inherited MyMethod(MyParam);` or shortened `inherited;`
- C++Builder: `MyBaseClass::MyMethod(MyParam);`

Comment: `MyBaseClass` isn't quite the same as `__super`. Is there an equivalent in C++Builder?

Comment: I agree, it's not quite the same. I'm not aware of an equivalent in C++Builder, but you could [declare a `typedef`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c).

Comment: A per unit `typedef TMyParentClassName __super` is still less repetition than repeating a TMyParentClassName a dozen times in your .cpp file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: how is calling `MyBaseClass::DoSomething()` different than calling `__super::DoSomething()`?

Comment: @WarrenP, the typedef would have to be per-class, not per-unit.

Comment: @remy Because you violate DRY. Imagine inserting another class in between MyBaseClass and MyDerivedClass. Inherited or __would find it, but the hard coded C++ code would not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know what `DRY` is.  In any case, if `MyDerivedClass` derives from `MyBaseClass`, then calling `MyBaseClass::DoSomething()` works.  If `MyDerivedClass` is later changed to derive from something else, then `MyBaseClass::` references have to be updated accordingly.  Using a typedef inside of `MyDerivedClass`, ie: `class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass { typedef MyBaseClass inherited; ... };` and calling `inherited::DoSomething()`, lessens that blow.  Then you only have to update one line when changing the ancestor of `MyDerivedClass`.

Comment: @Remy DRY is Don't Repeat Yourself and the comment above perfectly describes the different between inherited/__super and standard C++

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi, the equivalent is **inherited**.  You can see examples of it in use in the RTL and VCL sources.