# C++ cannot find type defined in template base class which inherits from the current template class

Tags: c++, templates, super, crtp, typename

I'm trying to write a variation of the [template class defining a `super` type idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c%20%22%20Super%20class%20idiom). The class `Inherit` introduces the type `Super` to denote the possibly very long super type, and also needs to know the derived type `New` to do some extra things which I'm not showing here.

This works fine if the type passed to `New` is not a template, but fails with templates. Here is a full example compiled with `clang++-3.8 -std=c++1y -Wall` (gcc gives the same output):

```
struct SomeBase {};

template<class New, class Base>
struct Inherit : Base {
    using Super = Inherit<New, Base>;
};

struct NonTemplate : Inherit<NonTemplate, SomeBase> {
    using X = Super;
    // compiles and is nice and short
};

template<class T>
struct Template : Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>
{
    using A = Super;
    // error: unknown type name 'Super'; did you mean 'NonTemplate::Super'?

    using B = typename Super;
    // error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'

    using C = Inherit::Super;
    // error: 'Inherit' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

    using D = typename Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>::Super;
    // compiles, but what's the point?
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

If I didn't need the `New` parameter I am also able to use `Inherit` with templates, but I really  need `New`. I could make the code compile by using option `D` but that defeats the whole purpose.

I have two questions:

1. What exactly is the language issue which prevents the type name `Super`
   from being known inside the class `Template` and why is that different in the `NonTemplate` case?
2. Does anyone have an idea for a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Depending name... `Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>` might have some specialization which may change the meaning of `Super`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>` is a *dependent base class*, i.e. the class depends on a template parameter. Names in dependent base class are hidden from unqualified lookup, so you need to qualify the name.

`typename` is needed because `Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>::Super` is a dependent name and the compiler needs you to tell it that it names a type, as it can only be certain at instantiation time.

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for an in-depth explanation of the `typename` keyword.

---

As for solutions, you could factor `Super` out into a type trait:

```
template<class New, class Base>
struct Inherit : Base {
};

namespace detail {
    template <class New, class Base>
    Inherit<New,Base> Super (const Inherit<New, Base>&);
}
template <class T>
using Super = decltype(detail::Super(std::declval<T>()));
```

This makes usage much simpler:

```
template<class T>
struct Template : Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>
{
    using D = Super<Template>;
};
```

---

If you find yourself needing this for multiple base classes, you could generalise it:

```
namespace detail {
    template <template <typename...> class T, class... Args>
    T<Args...> Super (const T<Args...>&);
}
template <template <typename...> class Base, class Derived>
using Super = decltype(detail::Super<Base>(std::declval<Derived>()));

template <typename T>
using InheritSuper = Super<Inherit,T>;

template<class T>
struct Template : Inherit<Template<T>, SomeBase>
{
    using D = InheritSuper<Template>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive solution! :) I wish there was no need for this complication, as it makes the usage a bit more complex (`Super` vs `Super<PotentiallyALongClassName>`), but it's still better than having to specify the complete base type.