# When using static cast, does it make more sense to cast as class type or object reference?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I just realized that I can use either to achieve the same effect. Are there any caveats? Which convention makes more sense?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class some_class {
public:
    void echo() {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
};

class other_class : public some_class {
public:
    void echo() {
        // Does it matter? 
        static_cast<some_class>(*this).echo();
        static_cast<some_class&>(*this).echo();
    }
};

int main() {
    other_class a;

    a.echo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You make an *upcast*, i.e. from derived to base. That is not needed here, a simple `some_class::echo()` is sufficient. In a *downcast* (e.g. in the CRTP framework) you usually go with the (const-)reference-to-derived version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first cast creates a temporary object of type `some_class`, initialized from `*this` by slicing, then calls `echo` on the temporary object, then destroys the temporary object.   If you made the `echo` function update a member variable of `some_class`, you would notice that `*this` actually did not get updated.

The second cast calls `some_class::echo();` function on the `*this` object, without creating anything.

Typically the second option is what you are aiming for.  As noted by davidhigh in comments, it is a cleaner code style (IMHO anyway) to simply write `some_class::echo();` instead of using the cast.

Comment: I'm currently using the static cast in this macro context which wouldn't work with the scope operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c/35420894#35420894

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get confused sometimes bouncing between Java and C++.