# Why aren't typename template parameters implicitly recognized as types?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, using-directives

Very often in C++ class definitions, especially in libraries, trait class etc., you see code similar to the following snippet:

```
template <typename Bar, typename Baz>
class Foo {
    using bar_type = Bar;
    using baz_type = Baz;
    // ... etc.
}
```

And only with these lines can you later refer to `Foo<A,B>::bar_type` or `Foo<C,D>:baz_type`. I'm wondering: Why doesn't the language standard require the compiler to automatically define types using the typename template parameters, i.e. allow removing the two using lines, and recognize `Foo<A,B>::Bar` as `A` and `Foo<C,D>::Baz` as `D`?

This should not even break existing code, since within Foo, the identifiers Bar and Baz are already taken anyway.

Comment: Because they might not be types.  E.g., they might be a value, e.g., the N in `template<class T, std::size_t N> struct array`

Comment: They aren't always needed, and exposing them means client code may become coupled to them (assuming you meant those aliases to be public.)

Comment: Another answer: Because it's trivial to do yourself.  Which was the answer given when someone asked why isn't there a `super` keyword in C++ (but I don't have the reference to that at hand).

Comment: @juanchopanza is right too, they're more like the names of parameters in a method decl than an actual defined value.

Comment: @davidbak: "*Which was the answer given when someone asked why isn't there a super keyword in C++*" To be fair, that answer has more to do with multiple inheritance. In C++, there isn't necessarily a single `super` class instance.

Comment: @NicolBolas - that too, but I distinctly remember an early C++ standards committee update in some magazine where it _was_ considered (the `super` keyword) by the committee until someone (forget who) said "just do `typedef xxx super`".

Comment: The names aren't part of the template. `template <typename> struct X; template <typename A> struct X; template <typename Q> struct X;` declares the same template three times. Just like for function parameters.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I actually found a reference right [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/180633/751579).

Comment: @KerrekSB that's worthy of an answer.

Comment: @davidbak: 1. I said "typename" parameters. Let me edit and emphasize that. 2. for_each is trivial to implement, and yet we have ranged for loops; and the same argument goes for anything that's mostly syntactic sugar.

Comment: @juanchopanza: 1. They could be protected by default. 2. Whoever is using Foo<A,B> knows A and B _anyway_...

Comment: @einpoklum 1. Same problem. 2. They don't know `A` as `Baz` or whatever.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Make that an answer please.

Comment: @einpoklum: Done :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza [they do know if they're the same.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter names aren't part of the entity that's being declared. This is true for both functions and templates. The following code only declares two separate entities:

```
extern void f(int, char, bool);
extern void f(int a, char b, bool c);
extern void f(int x, char b, bool z);

template <typename> struct X;
template <typename A> struct X;
template <typename T> struct X;
```

Note in particular that the following code is perfectly fine:

```
template <typename T> struct X { void f(); };   // X<T>::f not yet defined
template <typename U> void X<U>::f() {}         // now it's defined
```

All attempts at deriving additional structure from parameter names must deal with this situation. One of the most popular requests in this area are named function parameters; to date there has not been a satisfactory proposal for such an extension.

To some extent, all such proposals would require making the parameter names part of the declared entity. For functions, for example, that would raise the question whether parameter names would need to be mangled and exposed to the linker.

Comment: Who knows. One of the hidden implications of names of parameters becoming part of function signatures might be that it opens you up to companies like  [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.) suing your ass over it.

Comment: I'm repeatedly disheartened by people (not you obviously) who are somehow annoyed with questions regarding why the status quo is what it is, and downvote or vote to close with no comment - when there's a perfectly reasonable answer (which validates the rationale for the question.)

Comment: @einpoklum: I think this is a good question and I'm glad to have read the question and answer. However I have to admit that when I first read it, I was tempted to vote to close as not germane to stack overflow. The reason I guess is this line "Was this ever suggested? Discussed? Rejected?" I don't think that arbitrary historical inquiries into C++ make good SO questions -- the questions should be about programming, and ideally, of interest to a working programmer, rather than an academic or historian, IMO. Without that line, I probably up-vote it though. I'm only one sample point, YMMV.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: 1. It's not necessarily a historical inquiry, because in some cases people say "oh, yes, this is a standing proposal to the standard committee" and then you can go read that and realize it might even make it to the next standard. 2. Some programmers write code by inspiration of the theoretical/academic discussion of the programming language. So these issues are of relevance to them. Different strokes for different folks etc.