# Does C++ have a keyword which allows to refer to a base type from a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

For an example:

```
class some_base
{
 ... // some valid code
};

class derived : public some_base
{
  ...

  derived& operator=( const derived& that )
  {
    some_base::operator=( that );

    ...

    return *this;
};
```

It'd be good if we were able to use some keyword in a `derived's` assign operator instead of a `some_base` qualifier. Compiler knows a type we inherit from so it's not a problem, in my opinion.

So the question is does С++ provides an auxiliary keyword to simplify the coder's life ?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such mechanism in C++

Comment: Historically - It didn't exist. That's why I got used to writing `typedef some_base Parent;` at the top of the class. I am unaware if anything changed with newer standards of C++, though.

Comment: if you are using a microsoft's compiler you can use [__super](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/94dw1w7x.aspx)

Comment: Kind of similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143835/560648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compiler knows a type we inherit from so it's not a problem

Unless you derive from multiple base classes - in such case, how would compiler decide which one it is?

So no, there is no such keyword, all you can do is put one into your coding standard.

Comment: The proposal that almost got accepted, let the keyword be ambiguous for multiple base classes. That's not the reason why it's not in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers provide a base class keyword as an extension. It seems that variants of the name **[`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c)** are common, e.g. [Visual C++'s `__super`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx) (I would expect that as an intended plug-in replacement, Intel's compiler also supports `__super`). But standard C++ provides no such thing, although [there was once a proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180633/464581).

To achieve about the same, simply define a type alias `Base` in every class.

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180634/464581), user Roddy argues that such an alias should be `private` “to avoid the problem when the 'inherited' is erroneously omitted from a class but a subclass tries to use it”.