# c++ emulation of the "super" keyword

Tags: c++, inheritance, keyword

Until 'super' is implemented in c++, I'm looking for a way to emulate it myself.
Motivation: Here's a typical scenario:

```
class A
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

class B : public A
{
    void SomeMethod() override;
}

void B::DoSomething()
{
    A::SomeMethod();
}
```

All is well, until someone inserts a class in between:

```
class C : public A
{
    void SomeMethod() override;
}
```

and changes inheritance:

```
class B : public C {...}
```

In most cases I'd like the immediate base class to be called, which is not going to happen unless I explicitly replace all A:: calls with C:: calls.

A 'super' keyword would be of great use here, where it means: "use the immediate base, but issue a compiler error if ambiguous".

Reading some suggestions, I attempted to define as follows:

```
class A
{
    void SomeMethod();

    protected:
        using super = A;
}

class C
{
    void SomeMethod();

    protected:
        using super = C;
}

void B::DoSomething()
{
    super::SomeMethod();
}
```

However A::SomeMethod() was called instead of C::SomeMethod()...

How does the compiler treat multiple aliases with the same name?

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**: the suggested other question is an old one where the solutions might by improved using modern c++.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `super` is not going to be implemented in C++ because of multiple inheritance.

Comment: What compiler/platform are you targeting ?

Comment: Windows and Mac.

Comment: @gil_mo thats a shame - on windows/msvc theres a compiler extrension `__super`

Comment: I would dare say if someone inserts a class in between, then it must somehow be aware of the existing code and practices. If you have a 'using super = C' somewhere, then whoever added that class should be aware of it. You can't prevent stupid.

Comment: I'll bet it should be possbile as in the example implementation of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of but thats too much template magic for me to implement in under 10h.

Comment: @AlexG it's not about stupidity, it's mainly about having to tediously search & replace all places.

Comment: @gil_mo That you can often avoid by using a `using` or `typedef` alias.

Comment: The real point is to ask why C++ does not implement `super`.  The designer(s) of the language didn't see any gain from adding it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Since they allow multiple inheritance it was an easy thing to leave out as well.

Comment: All the 'multiple inheritance' argument is irrelevant. This keyword would be useful 95% of the times, and the compiler would not allow using it when ambiguity pops up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "super" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180601/using-super-in-c)

Comment: @BenjaminBihler that's a 2008 post, no modern c++.

Comment: the question is not specifically asking for an old c++ standard, its the answers that might be outdated, but not the question

Comment: It's not at all clear that calling `C::SomeMethod()` is the appropriate automatic change when that change in the class hierarchy is made. Class design is **design**; when the class hierarchy changes you have to analyze the effect that those changes have on your code to decide what, if anything, should be done in response.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this, but it does limit how you can use the class, is to make it a template.  In doing so you can make the base classes a template type and now you have generic names you can refer to to them by.  That would look like

```
struct A
{
    void do_something() { std::cout << "A::do_something\n"; }
};

template <typename Super>
struct B : Super
{
    void do_something() 
    { 
        std::cout << "B::do_something\n"; 
        Super::do_something(); 
    }
};

template <typename Super>
struct C : Super
{
    void do_something() 
    { 
        std::cout << "C::do_something\n"; 
        Super::do_something(); 
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B<A> b;
    b.do_something();
    C<B<A>> c;
    c.do_something();
}
```

which outputs

```
B::do_something
A::do_something
C::do_something
B::do_something
A::do_something
```

You can even user multiple inheritance and access each base individually like

```
template <typename Super1, typename Super2>
struct B : Super1, Super2
{
    void do_something() 
    { 
        std::cout << "B::do_something\n"; 
        Super1::do_something(); 
        Super2::do_something(); 
    }
};
```

Comment: One would probably default the template arguments to whatever the inheritance is supposed to be (so we can write `C<> c;` instead of leaving it up to users to recite the correct inheritance hierarchy every time). That or `using C = CImpl<B>;` after every class.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I like the using idea better.  I didn't want to sway the user one way or the other though so I left that to them to decide how they actually want to use it.

Comment: I've marked this reply as helpful, however AFAIK it can't serve as the final answer, as it requires large-scale refactoring of my code...

Answer (score 0):

The requirement doesn't make sense: *which* base class should be considered the super-class?

If your class has single inheritance, then you can ease the maintenance burden by adding a `using` declaration:

```
class B : public A
{
    using Base = A;
    //...
}
```

Then you have only one line that needs to be changed.